# filter multiple sheets using data validation

Tags: google-sheets

I have a workbook with four sheets and want to make a dashboard. In the dashboard I have 4 data validation drop down lists (Part, Date, Shift, Part Number). I want when someone selects the value from the drop list to look for the data that relate to the selections. I currently have `=FILTER('sheet1'!A5:FP,('sheet1'!C5:C=Dash!A6)*('sheet1'!A5:A=Dash!A4)*('sheet1'!H5:H=Dash!A8))`"Sheet 1" is the name of the sheet I want the data pulled from, however because the first parameter of `=FILTER` is range it wont allow me to reference my data validation dropdown found in A2. Is there a way to have the filter function look at what is in A2 and give me the data from the selected sheet, and how? Thank You in advance! [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking at the `indirect` [function in google sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377), please try:

```
=FILTER(
  Indirect(A2&"!A1:FP"),
  (Indirect(A2&"!C5:C")=Dash!A6)*(Indirect(A2&"!A5:A")=Dash!A4)* 
(Indirect(A2&"!H5:H")=Dash!A8)
)
```

Comment: As a side note for explanation, ```INDIRECT``` returns a cell reference specified by a string. For example ```INDIRECT(A2&"!A1")``` will reference the cell ```A1``` of ```Sheet1``` in your example.